# How can I loop 3 buttons in an espresso test

Tags: android, android-espresso

Can you help me with this? I am writing an espresso test. Here is the code:

```
 onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnControl1)).perform(click());
 SystemClock.sleep(delay);
 onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnControl2)).perform(click());
 SystemClock.sleep(delay);
 onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnControl3)).perform(click());
 SystemClock.sleep(delay);
```

I want to loop it. For example: to click these 3 buttons 20 times.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can just put it in a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnControl1)).perform(click());
    SystemClock.sleep(delay);
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnControl2)).perform(click());
    SystemClock.sleep(delay);
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnControl3)).perform(click());
    SystemClock.sleep(delay);
}
```